# how can i use arithmetic operations on class attributes?

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance

I am trying to write a code that can solve arithmetic operations. The classes `mult` and `plus` are meant to solve problems like:

```
e1 = mult(const(3),const(4))
e1 = plus(const(3),const(4)
```

and return a result (resp. 12 and 7)

Now the assignment from the lecturer wants us to write the program that can solve a problem like this:

```
e1 = mult(plus(const(3),const(4)),const(5)) # should print 35
e2 = plus(mult(const(3),const(4)),const(5)) # should print 12
```

I tried solving the problem using lists so that the constants are stored in lists(i.e `store_const`), then the classes `mult(const(n),const(n))` and `plus(const(n),const(n))` would solve the problem and return a result. My problem is for each class `mult`/`plus`, I created the method `eval` that adds or multiplies the `store_const[0]` and `[1]`, but every time I run the program: e1 returns 12 and e2 return 7

I figured this is because  `mult`/`plus` only take `store_const[0] = 3` and `store_const[1] = 4` and leaves out `store_const[2] = 5`.

So how can I solve this:

```
e1 = mult(plus(const(3),const(4)),const(5))
```

where the result of the `plus` is stored as a new `const(n)`, and then the `mult` class can execute to produce 35k

Here is my code:

```
class expr(object): #ignore class
   pass


class const(expr):
   store_const = [] #list to store constants

   def __init__(self, n): #initial constructor
       self.n = n
       const.store_const.append(self.n) #store constants in list


class binOp(expr): #sublcass of expr

   def __init__(self, expr1, expr2): #initial constructor arguments
      self.expr1 = expr1
      self.expr2 = expr2

class mult(binOp):
   def __int__(self, *args):
      super(mult, self).__init__(*args) #inheriting the superclass constructor arguments

   def eval(self):
      self.expr1 = const.store_const[0]
      self.expr2 = const.store_const[1]
      self.result = self.expr1 * self.expr2
      return self.result


class plus(binOp):
   def __init__(self, *args):
      super(plus, self).__init__(*args) #inheriting the superclass constructor arguments

   def eval(self):
      self.expr1 = const.store_const[0] #assigning the 1st elem of list to expr1
      self.expr2 = const.store_const[1] #assigning the 2nd elem of list to expr2
      self.result1 = self.expr1 + self.expr2
      return self.result1

#input
e1 = mult(plus(const(3), const(4)),const(5))
print e1.eval()
e2 = plus(mult(const(3), const(4)),const(5))
print e2.eval()

#output
12
7
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the consts in an outside collection if you give the const class an `eval` method. Also, your `binOp` eval methods will have to recursively call `eval` on its left and right arguments.

```
class expr(object): #ignore class
   pass


class const(expr):
   store_const = [] #list to store constants

   def __init__(self, n): #initial constructor
       self.n = n
   def eval(self):
       return self.n

class binOp(expr): #sublcass of expr

   def __init__(self, expr1, expr2): #initial constructor arguments
      self.expr1 = expr1
      self.expr2 = expr2

class mult(binOp):
   def __int__(self, *args):
      super(mult, self).__init__(*args) #inheriting the superclass constructor arguments

   def eval(self):
      return self.expr1.eval() * self.expr2.eval()


class plus(binOp):
   def __init__(self, *args):
      super(plus, self).__init__(*args) #inheriting the superclass constructor arguments

   def eval(self):
      return self.expr1.eval() + self.expr2.eval()

#input
e1 = mult(plus(const(3), const(4)),const(5))
print e1.eval()
e2 = plus(mult(const(3), const(4)),const(5))
print e2.eval()
```

Result:

```
35
17
```

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now because I was also thinking how I could assign the expr1 and expr2 directly to the const(n). Thanks a lot..

Comment: what if I wanted to print the constants i.e print str(e1) = (3+4)*5 and print str(e2) = (3*4)+5 using the str method? Becuase using your method str(e1) = 7 * 5 and str(e2) = 12 + 5

Comment: Each class should have a `__repr__` method that returns its string representation. Make sure that your binOp classes call `repr` on their arguments and not `eval`.

Comment: I haven't been taught yet on how to use '__repr__'.
Is it like  def __repr__(self):
                 return repr(self)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried solving the problem using lists so that the constants are stored in lists

I think that's your problem as you suspected:

> I figured this is because mult/plus only take store_const[0] = 3 and store_const[1] = 4 and leaves out store_const[2] = 5

As this is obviously an assignment, and you are almost there, I will only give you hints:

You don't need to store const. You can access them with `.n`:

```
>>> x = const(3)
>>> y = const(4)
>>> x.n
3
>>> y.n
4
```

In your `eval` methods, you have to "guess" what is the class of expr1 and expr2 and call `.eval` if it's `mult` or `plus` and `.n` if it's a `const`. 
In pseudo-code:

```
if expr1 is a const:
   new_expr1 = expr1.n
else:
   new_expr1 = expr1.eval()
if expr2 is a const:
   new_expr2 = expr2.n
else:
   new_expr2 = expr2.eval()
result = new_expr1 + new_expr2 #or * in the mult class
```

But you have to do that for the 2 expr (1 and 2) and there is a better way: as you may guess if `const` have a `eval` method that returns `.n`, then you don't have to "guess" and can do `self.expr1.eval()+self.expr2.eval()` (or `*` for the class `mult`).

`self.expr1.eval()` will return either `.n` for a constant, or the result of the mult/plus operation.